# What makes my richfaces combobox not working after first usage?

Tags: jsf, richfaces, jsf-1.2

I'm currently using JSF 1.2, and Richfaces 3.3.3.

I get a quite strange bug with a combobox in a rich:datatable :
The first time I click and select a value, it's working, and via ajax:support, it updates the page as required. But then, if I try to change the value in the combobox, it seems "blocked"... field is not editable, and the arrow not "clickable". If I click on another field of the page, then come back, it usually works better (but not always).

Here is the code :

```html
    <rich:column style="border:none;" id="KitCol">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Kit"/>
        </f:facet>
        <rich:comboBox id="kit" value="#{deployItem.kit}" 
            directInputSuggestions="true" defaultLabel="Enter kit name >
            <f:selectItems value="#{deployItem.kits}" />
            <a4j:support event="onchange" action="#{deployItem.kitChanged}"
                reRender="deployActions, deployTable">
                <f:setPropertyActionListener value="true" target="#{deployController.atLeastOneItem}" />
            </a4j:support>
        </rich:comboBox>
    </rich:column>
```

Would somebody have an idea about how to solve this issue ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a bug in RichFaces 3.3 combobox about similar cases. Try to use `<h:selectOneMenu>` instead.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but sadly, the combobox or something similar is quite necessary, due to the number of items I have to put in the list.

Comment: Have you tried using the `<h:selectOneMenu>` instead? What is the difference for your specific case? I don't think that the number of items would be a problem.

Comment: Problem is that it is long for a user to go (several times) in a list of more than 300 items to choose one, when typing 2 chars will limit the list usually to less than 10 items...